# Как указать тип временных данных при загрузке датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

Есть файлик с данными вида '%Y-%m-%d'

```
datetime_click
2017-03-01
2017-03-02
2017-03-03
2017-03-04
2017-03-05
```

Можно ли при загрузке его в датафрейм сразу указать для колонки формат datatime?
Или другими словами что подставить сюда?

```html
df = pd.read_csv('result.csv', dtype={'datetime_click':'????????????'})
```

Или каждый раз если я хочу фильтровать данные по времени мне надо конвертировать столбик с данными
таким вот образом

```html
def convert_to_datetime(row):
    prom_data = datetime.strptime(row['datetime_click'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    return prom_data
df['datetime_click'] = df.apply(convert_to_datetime, axis=1)
```

И только потом фильтровать с помощью следующего алгоритма

```html
startDate = '2017-03-03'
endDate = '2017-03-04'
startDate_datetime = datetime.strptime( startDate, '%Y-%m-%d' )
endDate_datetime = datetime.strptime( endDate, '%Y-%m-%d' )
df = df[(df['datetime_click'] >= startDate_datetime) & 
        (df['datetime_click'] <= endDate_datetime)]
```

Нельзя ли как то сразу использовать этот алгоритм?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [pd.read_csv(parse_dates=[...])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('result.csv', parse_dates=['datetime_click'])
```

Comment: Шедеврально! Огромное спасибо!